# How can I copy past+paste values from different cells from different worksheets to one?

Tags: excel, vba

I need your help.

I have a code that can copy values from different cells from a worksheet to another. I wanted to take that code and apply it to copy values from other files. However, I don't want to paste the values on the same column... and that's what happened. Can I change automatically the Range in each loop?

```
Sub Teste()

Dim NrCop As Integer 'this is the number of files I want

Set b = Workbooks.Open(Application.GetOpenFilename) 'the file that I want to past my values on
NrCop = InputBox("Quantos promotores são?")
Set a = Workbooks.Open(Application.GetOpenFilename) 'the files I want to copy the values from

For x = 1 To NrCop

    a.Activate
    Range("D4").Select 'this range is static
    Selection.Copy
    b.Activate
    Range("B3").Select ' for the next loop I want this range to change for C3
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    a.Activate
    Range("D5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    b.Activate
    Range("B4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
     a.Activate
    Range("D11").Select
    Selection.Copy
    b.Activate
    Range("B5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
     a.Activate
    Range("D37").Select
    Selection.Copy
    b.Activate
    Range("B6").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
     a.Activate
    Range("D48").Select
    Selection.Copy
    b.Activate
    Range("B7").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
     a.Activate
    Range("D74").Select
    Selection.Copy
    b.Activate
    Range("B8").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
     a.Activate
    Range("D100").Select
    Selection.Copy
    b.Activate
    Range("B9").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    a.Activate
    Range("D126").Select
    Selection.Copy
    b.Activate
    Range("B12").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    a.Activate
    Range("D152").Select
    Selection.Copy
    b.Activate
    Range("B13").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    a.Activate
    Range("D178").Select
    Selection.Copy
    b.Activate
    Range("B14").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    a.Activate
    Range("D204").Select
    Selection.Copy
    b.Activate
    Range("B15").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    a.Activate
    Range("D205").Select
    Selection.Copy
    b.Activate
    Range("B16").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
     a.Activate
    Range("D209").Select
    Selection.Copy
    b.Activate
    Range("B17").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    a.Activate
    Range("D212").Select
    Selection.Copy
    b.Activate
    Range("B18").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    a.Activate
    Range("D216").Select
    Selection.Copy
    b.Activate
    Range("B19").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Next x

End Sub
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Are all the files you want to get values from in the same format? Also, when you add data are you looking to add it below the previously pasted data?

Comment: The data are all in the same fromat. And I want to past the data on the next column of the previously pasted data

Comment: what determines the loop? the number of files chosen? or the value of `NrCop`? Which means one file can loop `NrCop` times?

Comment: obligatory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: ``NrCop`` determines the loop

Comment: @CatarinaRibeiro so for each `NrCop` you want the data to be placed on column to the right?

Comment: It is not clear what or how you are looping; you are defining a loop using `Quantos promotores são`  translated `All the Promoters are` should be a number, but this is not clear. Looping through files, and using `Application.GetOpenFilename`, you would have to insert `Application.GetOpenFilename` inside the loop.

Comment: It depends on what you are actually needing. If you want to open multiple files, one after the other, and copy the range from each file and paste to the next column. Or open a single file and then paste the data the next empty column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using arrays and variables simplifies code and speeds execution.

```
Sub test()
    Dim a As Workbook, b As Workbook
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, toWs As Worksheet
    Dim x As Integer, NrCop As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim vArray As Variant
    Dim vR() As Variant 'dynamic array

    Set b = Workbooks.Open(Application.GetOpenFilename) 'the file that I want to past my values on
    Set toWs = b.Sheets(1)

    NrCop = InputBox("Quantos promotores sao?")
    Set a = Workbooks.Open(Application.GetOpenFilename) 'the files I want to copy the values from
    Set Ws = a.Sheets(1)

    vArray = Array(4, 5, 11, 37, 48, 74, 100, 126, 152, 178, 204, 205, 209, 212, 216)
    n = UBound(vArray)
    ReDim vR(n)
    For i = 0 To n
        vR(i) = Ws.Range("d" & vArray(i))
    Next i

    For x = 1 To NrCop
        toWs.Range("b3").Offset(0, x - 1).Resize(n + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
    Next x

End Sub
```